# Can I call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths... inside moveRowAtIndexPath...?

Tags: ios, uitableview, reload

In my `UITableView` I have a particular cell (A) whose appearance is dependent on the order of all the other cells in the same section. So whenever the user drags a cell to a new position in the table view I need to update the contents of cell (A).

In my opinion the best way to do this would be to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPath:@[indexPathOfCellA]` inside a method that is called after the table view is done reordering the cells, something like `didMoveRowFromIndexPath:toIndexPath:`. Unfortunately there is no such method.

Hence I tried to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPath:@[indexPathOfCellA]` at the end of the `moveRowFromIndexPath:toIndexPath:` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
    NSString *element = [self.dataSource objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.dataSource insertObject:element atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
    [self updateInfoCellInTableView:tableView];
}
```

with the corresponding method:

```
- (void)updateExampleCellInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    UInt32 infoCellRow = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;
    NSIndexPath *indexPathForInfoCell = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:infoCellRow inSection:0];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathForInfoCell] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

**This does not work properly.**

When dragging a cell (A) to a new position (B) the old cell at that position (B) first moves up or down in order to make room for cell (A). But when I lift my finger to confirm the reordering cell (B) moves back to its original position (B) causing both cells to overlap. (I can see that because the cell's background is semi-transparent.)

My hypothesis is that it is not allowed to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPath:` from within `moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`. However, I could not find such a rule in Apple's Developer Docs.

Is that hypothesis correct? How can I update a particular cell after reordering the table view?

Answer (score 2):

I have worked on this and here is simple example. Please go through it once. It may help you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   tblData=[[UITableView alloc]init];
   [tblData setDataSource:self];
   [tblData setDelegate:self];
   [tblData setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 75, 320, 430)];
   [self.view addSubview:tblData];
   [tblData setEditing:YES animated:NO];

   mutArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   [mutArr addObject:@"Object 1"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"Object 2"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"Object 3"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"Object 4"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"Object 5"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"Object 6"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"Object 7"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"Object 8"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"Object 9"];
   [mutArr addObject:@"Object 10"];

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return mutArr.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
   cell.textLabel.text=[mutArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   return cell;

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{

   NSString *element = [mutArr objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
   [mutArr removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
   [mutArr insertObject:element atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginReorderingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   previousPosition=(int)indexPath.row;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndReorderingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This cell moved from :%d to :%ld position",previousPosition,(long)indexPath.row];

}
```

Here "previousPosition" is an integer which is declared as global variable.

Comment: `tableView:didEndReorderingRowAtIndexPath:` looks exactly like the method I was searching for. However, it's [undocumented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/) and hence I would refrain from using it since the app might get rejected and it will break when Apple decides to remove that method.